# Flutter custom bottom sheet shape and animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, shapes, bottom-sheet

I want to create a custom bottom sheet shape and animation like in this example:
[image: Bottom sheet]

Anyone knows a package for this or can guide me on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!